# Display traffic and traffic time in using iOS MapKit

Tags: ios, mapkit, apple-maps

I'll be using the MapKit framework and I'd like to know if it is possible to display traffic time, for example, from my house to my office.

Answer (score 3):

Traffic information isn't available in MapKit, but the Google Maps SDK does have it: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases

Comment: And it's really easy ! [mapViewGM setTrafficEnabled:YES];

Answer (score 2):

MapKit now includes traffic information, in a very similar fashion than Google Maps: [.showsTraffic](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapview/1452433-showstraffic)

Comment: This is also only available on iOS 9.0+

Answer (score 0):

Traffic information isn't provided by MapKit, but if you have a source for the data you can certainly display it on a MapKit map using `MKOverlay` or one of it's subclasses.

Comment: I could not find any 3rd Party API which provides data regarding traffic to add overlay to MapKit. Can you help me out with that?

Answer (score 0):

MapKit has traffic information and uses it internally to calculate travel time if you use MKDirectionsRequest. You can set start or arrival time/date and Apple calculates the travel time respecting rush hours etc.
[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirectionsRequest_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKDirectionsRequest)

You can use calculateETAWithCompletionHandler() to get just the travel time, without routing info. This should be much faster.

Comment: Can you specify where Apple docs says about traffic information using in MapKit directions? Your link doesn't contain any information about traffic.
Is it only for `calculateETAWithCompletionHandler` method or for `calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler` too?
Thanks!

Comment: If you click on "ArrivalDate" in the options list of that class, you can read "For example, for a trip that takes place during commute hours, the server might consider alternatives to routes that are typically congested at that time."